How to get Material 3 fixed accent colors in code?
There is androidx.compose.material3.tokens.ColorDarkTokens which define all the Material 3 color tokens to use in standard components:
internal object ColorDarkTokens {
...
    val OnPrimaryFixed = PaletteTokens.Primary10
    val OnPrimaryFixedVariant = PaletteTokens.Primary30
    val OnSecondary = PaletteTokens.Secondary20
    val OnSecondaryContainer = PaletteTokens.Secondary90
    val OnSecondaryFixed = PaletteTokens.Secondary10
    val OnSecondaryFixedVariant = PaletteTokens.Secondary30
...
    val OnTertiaryFixedVariant = PaletteTokens.Tertiary30
...
    val PrimaryFixed = PaletteTokens.Primary90
    val PrimaryFixedDim = PaletteTokens.Primary80
...
    val SecondaryFixed = PaletteTokens.Secondary90
    val SecondaryFixedDim = PaletteTokens.Secondary80
...
    val TertiaryFixed = PaletteTokens.Tertiary90
    val TertiaryFixedDim = PaletteTokens.Tertiary80
}

But when providing colors using lightColorScheme or darkColorScheme, there are no parameters to pass *Fixed / *FixedDim colors.
How can I get SecondaryFixedDim color in my Composables? So it can work with both light and dark theme. There is no MaterialTheme.colorScheme.SecondaryFixedDim.
